# How to execute code when textField content changes?

Tags: swift, macos

I've been trying for a while to solve this problem, but I am at a loss.

Using Xcode 8.3 and Swift 3 (I'm adapting an app for mac), I have a textField named ServiceName, and I would like to execute some code when the content of this text field changes. I remember than in the past this could be done in the interface builder, but it looks no longer possible, and I don't know ho to do it in the code. I'm quite new to swift, and I don't really understand how delegates work, so could you please explain me in detail if it is needed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I would like to update a label while users are writing data in a textField

Answer (score 0):

- In Interface Builder connect the delegate of the text field to the target class.
- In the target class adopt the protocol `NSTextFieldDelegate`.
- In the target class override `controlTextDidChange` for example

  ```
  override func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

      if let textField = notification.object as? NSTextField {
          let string = textField.stringValue
          // do something with the text

      } else {
         super.controlTextDidChange(notification)
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm really sorry :/, I don't understand what the target class is. Could you be a little bit more specific please?

Comment: The target class is the class where you want to monitor the text field changes.

Comment: Is that the viewController?

Comment: If you want to monitor in the view controller, yes.

Comment: I am currently using the textField as an action in the viwController, but this only triggers when the enter key is pressed

Comment: Ok, but I can't connect the diligate there. Should I just drag and drop it like an outlet?

Comment: The notification `controlTextDidEndEditing` does the same as the action. If you can connect (control-drag) the action you can connect the delegate, too. Did you add `NSTextFieldDelegate` to adopt the protocol.